# Fetching child sum from Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, executefetchrequest

Lets say I have three Entitys.
**Person:**
name
address
(to-many-salary) and (to-many-loans)

**Salary:**
income
tax
Rel: (to-one-Person)

**Bills**
amount
Rel: (to-one-person)

How do I perform a fetch that have a result like this:

John Doe, SUM>income, SUM>amount
Eva Doe, SUM>income, SUM>amount

Using Swift

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you :) I dont know how I can be more specific. Im listing the database with attributes and relations, showing the results I'm after, the language and tagging with related words :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably most easily done using Key Value Coding "collection operators" (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)) rather than a fetch.  For each `person`:

```
let name = person.name
let totalIncome = person.valueForKeyPath("salary.@sum.income")
let totalLoans = person.valueForKeyPath("loans.@sum.amount")
```

If performance is an issue, you might improve things by amending the fetch request (for the Person objects) to "prefetch" the related `Salary` and `Bills` objects:

```
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["salary", "loans"]
```

Alternatively, it is possible to retrieve the required information all in one fetch, though I do not recommend it because it requires changing the fetchRequest to return an array of dictionaries rather than an array of `NSManagedObjects`.  This makes subsequent processing (eg. populating your table view) more difficult.

```
// Define NSExpression and NSExpressionDescription for the total income
let incomeED = NSExpressionDescription()
incomeED.expression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "salary.@sum.income")
incomeED.name = "totalIncome"
incomeED.expressionResultType = .Integer64AttributeType
// Define NSExpression and NSExpressionDescription for the total amount
let amtED = NSExpressionDescription()
amtED.expression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "loans.@sum.amount")
amtED.name = "totalLoans"
amtED.expressionResultType = .Integer64AttributeType
// specify attributes and expressions to fetch
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name", incomeED, amtED]
// specify dictionary return type (required to process NSExpressions)
fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```

The result of the fetch will be an array of dictionaries; each dictionary will have keys "name", "totalIncome" and "totalLoans" (with corresponding values).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am already using that solution today, but i thought it would be better to do this in the fetch? Speed? Memory usage? Im new with Swift and Xcode, so just asking :)
Im using the data in at UITableview.

Comment: @VegarFlo I think the KVC method is best, but I've updated my answer with details of the alternative method for info.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) I will do as you say and use the KVC. Just thought it would give better performance by changing the fetch. :)

Comment: The KCV might be fast. Measure before you change the code. It all depends on what's already in memory. https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/