# Fetching child count from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Lets say I have two Entitys. Item: name (to-many-Attribute)

Attribute: income: (to-one-Item)

**Firstly**, I follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556561/fetching-child-sum-from-core-data) to get the `sum`.

```
let totalIncome = item.value(forKeyPath: "attribute.@sum.income")
```

But `totalIncome` I get is `Any` type, not `Int` as the `income`. How to make it work?
[image]

**Secondly**, if I get the `count` number of the incomes, how to write the code?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work

```
let totalIncome = item.value(forKeyPath: "attribute.@sum.income") as? Int ?? 0
```

Comment: Great! @Asperi You really help me a lot.